# How to build an image from an str containing the binary data?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a byte string, and trying to convert it into a file but I keep getting an error:

```
OS Error cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x03BBD330>
```

The code that I've implemented is below:

```
def test_view(request):
    with open("test_json.json") as imageFile:
        b=bytearray(json.load(imageFile)["IMAGE_DATA"], 'utf8')

        print(b)

    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
    image.save(response, "JPEG")
    return response
```

The byte string is read from a json file, it looks like this, but it is much longer, I've just copied some characters.

```
"b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x00`\\x00`\\x00\\x00\\xff\\xdb\\x00C\\x00\\x05\\x04\\x04\\x04\\x04\\x03\\x05\\x04\\x04\\x04\\x06\\x05\\x05\\x06\\x08\\r\\x08\\x08\\x07\\x07\\x08\\x10\\x0b\\x0c\\t\\r\\x13\\x10\\x14\\x13\\x12\\x10\\x12\\x12\\x14\\x17\\x1d\\x19\\x14\\x16\\x1c\\x16\\x12\\x12\\x1a#\\x1a\\x1c\\x1e\\x1f!!!\\x14\\x19$\\'$ &\\x1d ! \\xff\\xdb\\x00C\\x01\\x05\\x06\\x06\\x08\\x07\\x08\\x0f\\x08\\x08\\x0f \\x15\\x12\\x15                                                  \\xff\\xc0\\x00\\x11\\x08\\x01&\\x02q\\x03\\x01\"\\x00\\x02\\x11\\x01\\x03\\x11\\x01\\xff\\xc4\\x00\\x1f\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x05\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05\\x06\\x07\\x08\\t\\n\\x0b\\xff\\xc4\\x00\\xb5\\x10\\x00\\x02\\x01\\x03\\x03\\x02\\x04\\x03\\x05\\x05\\x04\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x01}\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x00\\x04\\x11\\x05\\x12!1A\\x06\\x13Qa\\x07\"q\\x142\\x81\\x91\\xa1\\x08#B\\xb1\\xc1\\x15R\\xd1\\xf0$3br\\x82\\t\\n\\x16\\x17\\x18\\x19\\x1a%&\\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\\x83\\x84\\x85\\x86\\x87\\x88\\x89\\x8a\\x92\\x93\\x94\\x95\\x96\\x97\\x98\\x99\\x9a\\xa2\\xa3\\xa4\\xa5\\xa6\\xa7\\xa8\\xa9\\xaa\\xb2\\xb3\\xb4\\xb5\\xb6\\xb7\\xb8\\xb9\\xba\\xc2\\xc3\\xc4\\xc5\\xc6\\xc7\\xc8\\xc9\\xca\\xd2\\xd3\\xd4\\xd5\\xd6\\xd7\\xd8\\xd9\\xda\\xe1\\xe2\\xe3\\xe4\\xe5\\xe6\\xe7\\xe8\\xe9\\xea\\xf1\\xf2\\xf3\\xf4\\xf5\\xf6\\xf7\\xf8\\xf9\\xfa\\xff\\xc4\\x00\\x1f\\x01\\x00\\x03\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05\\x06\\x07\\x08\\t\\n\\x0b\\xff\\xc4\\x00\\xb5\\x11\\x00\\x02\\x01\\x02\\x04\\x04\\x03\\x04\\x07\\x05\\x04\\x04\\x00\\x01\\x02w\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x11\\x04\\x05!1\\x06\\x12AQ\\x07aq\\x13\"2\\x81\\x08\\x14B\\x91\\xa1\\xb1\\xc1\\t#3R\\xf0\\x15br\\xd1\\n\\x16$4\\xe1%\\xf1\\x17\\x18\\x19\\x1a&\\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\\x82\\x83\\x84\\x85\\x86\\x87\\x88\\x89\\x8a\\x92\\x93\\x94\\x95\\x96\\x97\\x98\\x99'"
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: @NinjaKitty This line:  image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what exactly is the best solution to this issue because the problem you're running into is that `json.load(imageFile)["IMAGE_DATA"]` is going to return `"b'bytes'"`, which when it converts to bytearray, you're doing `bytearray("b\'bytes\'")`, which is wrong.

Also this behavior is specific between JSON parsers, and different JSON parsers might interpret differently

Either strip the `b''` that's wrapping your bytestring, or do an `ast.literal_eval()`

```
def test_view(request):
    with open("test_json.json") as imageFile:
        b = bytearray(
            ast.literal_eval(
                json.load(imageFile)["IMAGE_DATA"], 'utf8')

        print(b)

    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
    image.save(response, "JPEG")
    return response
```

Comment: @Dasith I saw your edit, and I have to say that you should not use `eval`. Please use `ast.literal_eval` as it should give you the same result, but not as much of a security risk.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you! I'll try it again.